# Making a button open a hyperlink

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've just started with Xamarin and C# to do some iOS development. I'm trying to make a button open a web page in Safari. I have added the button in the XCode visual editor and dragged the button into the code view to start using it in Xamarin.

I'm getting the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270741/partial-class-declaration-error-in-monotouch-hello-world-tutorial) although I can't put the code in the view as the answer suggests I should as I need access to UIApplication to open the web page in Safari.

Here is my code:

**Login.cs:**

```
partial void webLink (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("http://www.google.com/"));
}
```

And the error:

```
A partial method implementation is missing a partial method declaration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you added a `UIButton` in `Xcode` and then you also dragged the newly created `UIButton` to `Assistant editor` and named your instance e.g. `btnOpenGoogle`.

Next you need to implement the `TouchUpInside` event handler in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
btnOpenGoogle.TouchUpInside += HandleBtnOpenGoogleTouchUpInside;
```

And somewhere in your code create the `HandleBtnOpenGoogleTouchUpInside` method:

```
private void HandleBtnOpenGoogleTouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("www.google.com"));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an IBAction,

```
- (IBAction)ButtonName:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
}
```

Just replace the 'ButtonName' with the name of your existing button, and then connect everything to the files owner in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be 
`private/public void webLink (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)`
instead of 
`partial void webLink (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)` ?
I don't think you should have partial.